# Scheme regular expression match

Tags: scheme, racket

Is there a simpler way of writing in scheme

> (eqv? (regexp-match "0x" "0x1234") #t)

#f

> (eqv? (regexp-match "0x" "1234") #f)

#t

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
(regexp-match? #rx"0x" "...some-string...")
```

Note that the `#rx` means that the regexp is precompiled and included in your code.  It's
also better to do that since it protects you from writing confused code and swapping the
arguments.

BTW, something like

```
(regexp-match? #rx"^0x" "...some-string...")
```

is probably more useful.

See also the [Guide pages](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/guide/regexp.html) to learn how to use
regular expressions in PLT, and the [reference page](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/regexp.html)
for a complete description.